# Convert 24 bit signed int signal to 16 bit signed int signal

Tags: c++, audio, casting, signal-processing

To put it as simply as I can.

1. I receive data from device and the signal is 24 bit signed int.
2. I want to create 16 bit WAV file.
3. For this purpose I want to keep writing upcoming audio buffer with 256 samples to *.wav file stream.
4. How can I convert buffer values (well values written in simple pointer to 256 element array) from [24 bit signed int] to [16 bit signed int].

Is there any scaling value? For example when I wanted to cast [24 bit signed int] to [24 bit signed double] I did it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
   bufferInDouble = *((int*)bufferRawData[currentPan]+i) / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

Any similar method could be there?

Comment: Is the device sampling a band limited signal? Are you oversampling at 24bit?

Comment: Sorry :D I am a bit newbie when it comes to all those bit/data operations. In the device documentation there is an info: 
"System handles all data with a 24-bit signal path, regardless of the I/O format. You can record and play back 16-bit or 24-bit audio files at any supported sample rate". I wonder if that's enough for your answer.

Comment: In that case i think @jaket's answer will suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is going to vary depending on whether you're 24-bit data is packed or is just 24-bits stored in a 32-bit word. I'm going to assume it is not packed and is left justified within the integer because that is most common.

The technique is to simply shift the data down into a 16-bit data type

```
ABCDEFxx => ABCD
```

Here I've shown the nibbles of a 32-bit integer where `ABCDEF` contain the 24-bit audio data and the `xx` byte contains nothing of value. Shifting right by 16 will discard the `EFxx`.

```
short outBuffer[256]
int* inBuffer = ((int*)bufferRawData);
for (int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; ++i)
{
    outBuffer[i] = (short)(inBuffer[i] >> 16);
}
```

On a side note, it is often desirable when reducing the bit-depth to add some low level noise in the LSB to reduce the quantization distortion. This is known as dither. For information refer to this article on wikipedia [Dither](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)

Comment: Thank you. It worked, now I can recognize words in my created *.wav though my signal is 0.5 shorter than original and goes 2x faster. Looks like I am missing a pan and listening only to the samples from left one... But it's separate problem I have to handle now.

Comment: Dithering is not optional if you want to reduce the bit depth of real 24-bit audio. If you skip the dithering step then you introduce distortion, admittedly at a very low level, but audible if the signal has a huge dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is to divide by 256.  Note that *bit-shifting right* won't work portably with `signed int`s (which are specified in your question): [5.8/3 in the C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) says behaviour of `E1 >> E2`, where `E1` is a negative signed value, is *implementation defined*.

An alternative that may retain higher audio quality is to find the highest amplitude values in the existing data (so you can only do this if you receive all the data before starting scaling) - let's call it M - then work out a scaling factor F such that that highest value has a new amplitude that's as high as 16 bit signed values can go: i.e. 32767.

```
M / F = 32767.0, so
F = M / 32767.0
```